# How to make multiple BigQuery JSON_EXTRACT fields efficient?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query that extracts lots of data from a big and complex json_string. A bit like this:

```
SELECT
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_string, "$.value1") AS value1,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_string, "$.value2") AS value2,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_string, "$.value3") AS value3,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_string, "$.value4") AS value4,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_string, "$.value5") AS value5,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_string, "$.value6") AS value6,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_string, "$.value7") AS value7,
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_string, "$.part1.part2.part3.value8") AS value8,
...
```

I'm concerned that each call to JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR has to parse the json_string and would therefore make this query very inefficient.

Is there a good way to improve this?

Comment: If the json is consistent you could try to import it as part of the table https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data#loading_denormalized_nested_and_repeated_data

Comment: Don't quite get that. The json is a string based field in the table. So changes per row.

Comment: I mean the json schema not the data it contains - are the keys always the same?

Comment: Same schema but properties may be missing. I think I've worked out a way. I pass the json_string into a js function that processes the json and returns a STRUCT with all the data I need. Seems to work well as long as the json_string isn't too big. Running javascript to parse seems a lot slower than using  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you worried about efficiency?  Is your query running slowly? BigQuery can efficiently handle more than you can likely throw at it.

Comment: The final queries will be on terabits of data. Doing an inefficient query on 10k rows can take 50 seconds. 10 million may take some time!